# Hide/display of 3 textboxes on selection of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 radio buttons. On selection of one I want to display 3 text boxes and hide it on selection of other.

Here is the code.

These are my 2 radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="type"> Fresher

<input type="radio" name="type"> Experienced
```

On click of radio button experienced I want to display these 3 text box.

```
Company Name: <input type="text"  hidden="true"/> <br/>
Designation: <input type="text" hidden="true"/> <br/>
Year_of_Experience: <input type="text"  hidden="true"/> <br/>
```

Please help me out with javascript for this as new to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this as follows. First change your HTML to this:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Fresher"> Fresher
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Experienced"> Experienced

<div id="textboxes" style="display: none">
    Company Name: <input type="text" hidden="true"/> 
    Designation: <input type="text" hidden="true"/> 
    Year_of_Experience: <input type="text" hidden="true"/> 
</div>
```

What this code adds to your code is to have a value for the radio buttons. This allows us to make a selection based on which radio button was selected. Secondly, the input fields are grouped together in a `<div>` to allow for easy hiding of the three input fields. After you have modifief your HTML as such, include jQuery on your website and use this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="type"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Experienced') {
            $('#textboxes').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#textboxes').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You can see how this works using this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pHsyj/

Comment: i know its stupid but can you please let me know which jQuery i must add??  will the below serve the purpose                         <script typ="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">

Comment: @user3367831 Yes that should be sufficient. I have updated the JSFiddle to show that it works with jQuery 1.7.2. But if you have the option, you should go with latest version: 1.11.0.

Comment: But this is not working in my proj. i have placed the script tag and jquery code inside head tag and then my body tag starts. Is that correct or should i make any changes??

Comment: @user3367831 There are two errors on how you include the jQuery library. First, you use `typ="text/javascript"` which should be `type="text/javascript"`. Secondly, the `src` attribute does not point to a valid file as your are missing the http:// prefix. The correct include code is: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` Oh, you must include the jQuery library *before* the `$(function()` code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
$(function(){
$('input[name="type"]').on('click', function(){
if ($(this).val() == 'Experienced') {
$('#textboxes').show();
}
else {
$('#textboxes').hide();
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Fresher"> Fresher
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Experienced"> Experienced
<div id="textboxes" style="display: none">
CompnyName:<input type="text" hidden="true"/> 
Designation:<input type="text" hidden="true"/> 
Year<input type="text" hidden="true"/> 
</div>

Comment: @user3367831 Could you email the complete code to me (see my [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2071395/erik-schierboom) for my email)?

Comment: Hey i have fixed the prob. Thanks a lot for your help. It was just a small mistake that i should have closed the script tag of jquery src and open a new script tag for function. i realised it late.

Comment: @user3367831 Great news! Could you accept my answer as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best example.Try something like this.,this is a sort of example

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){

if($(this).val()=="other")
{
    $("#otherAnswer").show();
}
else
{
       $("#otherAnswer").hide(); 
}

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wc2GS/8/

I guess this would solve your probs

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" name="type" id='frsradio'> Fresher
<input type="radio" name="type" id='expradio'> Experienced <br>

<input type="text" class='txbx' hidden="true"/> <br/>
 <input type="text" class='txbx' hidden="true"/> <br/>
<input type="text" class='txbx' hidden="true"/> <br/>

   $(function() {
        $('#expradio').click(function() {
            $('.txbx').attr('hidden',false);
        });           
        $('#frsradio').click(function() {
            $('.txbx').attr('hidden',true);
        });
    });
```

[WORKING jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/7P9Ew/10/)

Answer (score 0):

See there is no unique identity available for your html elements, i just given this code by thinking in a generic manner.

Try,

```
$('input[name="type"]:eq(1)').change(function(){
     $('input[type="text"]').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="type" onClick ="radio"> Fresher
<input type="radio" name="type" onClick ="radio">  Experienced
```

on click of radio button experienced i want to display these 3 text box.

```
<input type="text"  hidden="true" class="text"/> <br/>
 <input type="text" hidden="true" class="text"/> <br/>
<input type="text"  hidden="true" class="text"/> <br/>
```

and javascript:-

```
<script>
 function radio()
{
     var result = document.getElementsByClassName('text'").style.display="none";

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="fresher"> Fresher
<input type="radio" name="type" value="exp"> Experienced 

<br/>

<input class="box" type="text"  hidden="true"/> <br/>
<input class="box" type="text" hidden="true"/> <br/>
<input class="box" type="text"  hidden="true"/> <br/>
```

Script

```
$("input[type='radio']").on('change',function(){
if($(this).val() == "exp")
   $('.box').show('slow');
else
    $('.box').hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vk24X/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
<input type="radio" name="type" id="fresh"> Fresher
<input type="radio" name="type" id="exp"> Experienced 
<input type="text" class="hid" hidden="true"/> <br/>
<input type="text" class="hid" hidden="true"/> <br/>
 <input type="text" class="hid"  hidden="true"/> <br/>

 $("#fresh").change(function(){
     $('.hid').css("style","display:none");  
 });

 $("#exp").change(function(){
     $('.hid').css("style","display:block");  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For default hide the text boxes In OnRender Complete Method you need hide the three textbox for that you put the below code.

                    $("#textbox 1").hide();
                    $("#textbox 2").hide();
                    $("#textbox 3").hide();
```

You need to write the code in Radio button on change.

```
 Using the Id get the value of radio button

                    var val=$('#radioId').val;

                      if(val=='Fresher')
        {
                    $("#textbox 1").show();
                    $("#textbox 2").show();
                    $("#textbox 3").show();
                    }
                   else if (val=='Experienced'){

                    $("#textbox 1").hide();
                    $("#textbox 2").hide();
                    $("#textbox 3").hide();

                     }
```