# Need help getting a text box to show based on Radio box selection

Tags: javascript, html

I am not a developer but I do like to delve and in this case I have been asked to help out making some small changed to an old site, I have completed most of it like adding ReCapchta but I am struggling with just one thing I would like to add to it.

All I am trying to do is get a Text Box to show if a Radio Box is selected to "Other" and in addition this field should be REQUIRED but only if Other is selected in the Radio box above obviously.

I have tried a number of things, mostly based on this article...
[Hide/display of 3 textboxes on selection of radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552443/hide-display-of-3-textboxes-on-selection-of-radio-button)

But I cannot get it to work it just never shows, if I remove the Hidden and Display tags it shows correctly so I know the layout etc. is right, it's just getting this JavaScript to play ball.

===========================================================

### JavaScript located in Header...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input[name="BodyType"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
            $('#textboxes').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#textboxes').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

===========================================================

### HTML Table Defining the Radio Boxes

```
<table width="900" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<td align="center"><span class="tablebodytxt2"><strong>VEHICLE BODY TYPE:</strong></span><br>
    <table>
        <td width="0" align="center" valign="top">
    <span class="tablebodytxt">
        <input type="radio" name="BodyType" required value="Convertible" id="BodyType">Convertible
        <input type="radio" name="BodyType" required value="Coupe" id="BodyType">Coupe
        <input type="radio" name="BodyType" required value="Crossover" id="BodyType">Crossover
        <input type="radio" name="BodyType" required value="Hatchback" id="BodyType">Hatchback
        <input type="radio" name="BodyType" required value="MPV" id="BodyType">Multi-Purpose (MPV)
        <input type="radio" name="BodyType" required value="Pick-Up" id="BodyType">Pick-Up (UTE)
        <input type="radio" name="BodyType" required value="Sedan" id="BodyType">Sedan
        <input type="radio" name="BodyType" required value="Saloon" id="BodyType">Saloon
    <input type="radio" name="BodyType" required value="SUV" id="BodyType">Sports Utility (SUV)
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="BodyType" required value="Other" id="BodyType">Other: (Please specify below!)</span></label></td>
    </table>
```

===========================================================

### DIV Header, this is what should appear only when OTHER has been selected in the Radio Table above...

```
<div id="textboxes" class="tablebodytxt21" style="display: none">
Specify:<input type="text" required class="formtxt"  hidden="true"/>
</div>
```

===========================================================

It just does not show unless I removed the Hidden and Display tags, I have tried playing with the ID and NAME tags but no luck. :(

Comment: FYI: I removed the `php`-tag since the question doesn't involve PHP in any way. When posting a question, only add tags that are relevant to your issue.

Comment: have you experience debugging? add a console.log($(this).val()) under the click event, does it show 'Other'? if the required tag needs to be added dynamically you can do it like this document.getElementById("edName").required = true and document.getElementById("edName").required = false so when its shown make it true and when its hidden make it false

Comment: Thanks I did realise that with the PHP Tag, there is PHP involved in this page but it doesn't come into this part of the question.

Comment: No I have no debugging experience just trying it and seeing, if you can point me in the right direction I would be more than happy to learn, it is something I don't know where to start with \ what tools I need etc.

Comment: I think the word debugging was probably all I needed to hear in fact, not being a web developer I was a little stuck at trouble shooting this but googling Debugging JavaScripts seem to have given me what I need to figure this out thanks.

Comment: That said I haven't had a change to get back to it so I cannot advise solution yet, but will in coming weeks hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anyone who looked at this but I managed to resolve this myself using my old trusted suck it and see method as I got lost trying to use the Google Debugger on my own code, oh well.

Anyway as I didn't get an answer here I repharsed the question here: [Code to display boxes based on Radio Checkboxes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710697/code-to-display-boxes-based-on-radio-checkboxes-not-working)

This in the end got me the result I was looking for.

Essentially the reaosn it was not working was I tried the Script Code in the Header & the Body both above and below the code.

However I did not try it below the body which was where it needed to sit apparently for reasons I don't understand and need to look into, thanks anyway to anyone who looked.

Hopefully this thread will help someone else with a simliar problem in the future.