# Code to display boxes based on Radio Checkboxes not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have found the following Code Snippet, but I cannot get it to work on this site or even a black test page, not sure what I am missing?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/technologrich/tT48f/4/

I have tried moving the script part of the code before and \ or after the HTML, I have also tried moving it between HEAD and BODY but it just ignores it and always displays the boxes, sure I am missing something simple but have no idea what it is?

The code below is a plain HTML page I have created so I could rule everything else out, in my mind this should work but clearly not!

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script type="text/jquery" src="scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Show textboxes
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r1" value="Show">Do nothing
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r2" value="Nothing">
      </p>Wonderful textboxes:

     <div class="text">
       <p>Textbox #1
         <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
       </p>
     </div>

     <div class="text">
       <p>Textbox #2
         <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">
       </p>
     </div>

    <script type="text/jquery">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".text").hide();

            $("#r1").click(function () {
               $(".text").show();
               document.getElementById("text").required = true;
            });

            $("#r2").click(function () {
              $(".text").hide();
              document.getElementById("text").required = false;
            });
        });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

No matter what I do it just does not run the script, I have tried putting it in HEADER, BODY, above HTML part, below HTML part the lot but it just ignores it!

I guess I should also mention I have added the following two lines to the code linked...

```
document.getElementById("text").required = true;
document.getElementById("text").required = false;
```

However I have obviously tried with and without these in case this was the issue but no luck.

Other things worth mentioning...

1. The Site already had JQuery.min.js in place and reference however this maybe a version for 2006 which does not support it so I downloaded jquery-3.4.1.min.js placed that next to it and tried with this too.

Either way not matter what I do these boxes always just display from the start, I am clearly missing something but am clueless to what.

Thanks

Comment: Have you forgotten to include jQuery in your page?

Comment: did you try putting the script at the bottom of the page? might just be that it is run before the elements have actually been rendered.

Comment: The JS fiddle you link to works for me, but it does require clicking on the `<input>` elements which feels a little odd, does it work in your browser that way? If not, can you explain what you expect to happen, and what happens, or doesn't happen, instead?

Comment: @JoachimHaglund I did, still no luck.

Comment: @DavidThomas What I am trying to do is get a box just one of these will do to show based on a previous Radio Checkbox, on the Live Page there are a number of Radio Boxes to select Vehicle Type, if someone selects OTHER then I want another box to appear with REQUIRED parameter so this has to be filled in too.

Comment: @DavidThomas Oh and what doesn't happen, is those boxes in this Test HTML don't disappear I just see them 100% of the time. I just added the another JScript to display the Date & Time in a popup, just to confirm JScript is working and that runs fine, confused. Thanks!

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to add those details?

Comment: @sigmus Maybe but I don't think so, firstly the page already had JQuery.min.js in place and referenced with: 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
However I was worried that maybe out of date and didn't support this function or something so I put a new one next to it and referenced it using...
<script type="text/jquery" src="scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @DavidThomas yes will do, sorry wasn't clear if you would get notification if I edited it, new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is dependent on JQuery, so we need to give access to it. In this case, I added a link in the line `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">`

Next, I moved your script to below the body and it worked perfectly.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Show textboxes
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r1" value="Show">Do nothing
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r2" value="Nothing">
  </p>Wonderful textboxes:
  <div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #1
      <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #2
      <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".text").hide();
      $("#r1").click(function () {
          $(".text").show();
          document.getElementById("text").required = true;
      });
      $("#r2").click(function () {
          $(".text").hide();
          document.getElementById("text").required = false;
      });
  });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: AAAAHHH FFS! So simple, I had the JQUERY in place actually but forgot it first post, the problem was simply it needed to be below the BODY, I tried Above HTML, Below HTML (WITHIN BODY) and in the HEADER! I did not however try it below the body. Balls, oh well thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to Insert jquery in your page also you are using

```
document.getElementById()
```

and **id** is **text1** and **text2** not **text**

```html
        <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        </head>
        <body>

        <p>Show textboxes
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r1" value="Show">Do nothing
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r2" value="Nothing">
        </p>Wonderful textboxes:
        <div class="text">
        <p>Textbox #1
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30" required>
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
        <p>Textbox #2
        <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30" required>
        </p>
        </div>
        </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".text").hide();
            $("#r1").click(function () {
                $(".text").show();
                document.getElementById("text1").required = true;
            });
            $("#r2").click(function () {
                $(".text").hide();
                document.getElementById("text2").required = false;
            });
        });
        </script>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thats I did have this in fact but forgot tot copy it over, however I have the file locally on the server and referrence it there instread of using an external link like above.

Comment: Quick question though? Is it not bad practice to rely on an external lnk like above, what is that link changes the code breaks, or is this a common way to do it to reduce overhead?

Comment: @Ungifted I have modified the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `click` event for check box, you should use `change` event, click event always fire even if radiobutton is checked, but if you use change event it will only fire when radio button check (single time).

here is update js snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $("#r1").change(function () {
        $(".text").show();       
    });
    $("#r2").change(function () {
        $(".text").hide();
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but I do want to to work each time as if they click another radio I want the box to hide itself again. Still useful to know thanks. :)